# is there anyway to replace iframe with simple ajax code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

i heard that ajax has much more advantages over iframe, and yet i've seen too many people use ajax and iframe both at the same time.

is there anyway i can replace my iframe to load a CMS board using ajax?

http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/xe/page_FIsv96

my website is the link above, and i put an iframe inside the .list div that appears when you click on the 'click me' button.

i know that following code updates old data with new data,

```
$("#load").on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#old").fadeOut(function () {
    $(this).load("/kz0r47en/show #new", function () {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
});
```

but do not know the codes to replace  with ajax

can anyone help me get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.load()` **IS** Ajax. It's a wrapper for jQuery's $.ajax() along with some special sauce that allows it to target specific elements on a page. So...as it stands, the code you have **is** Ajax. It's just not written as `$.ajax()`. Nothing to change.